# Hadoop wordcount unable to run - need help on decoding the hadoop error message

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, word-count

I need some help on figuring out why my job failed.  I built a single 
node cluster just to try it out. I followed the example [here](http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-multi-node-cluster/).

Everything seems to be working correctly.  I formatted the namenode and am able to connect to the jobtracker, datanode, and namenode via the web interface.  I am able to start and stop all the hadoop services.

However, when I try to run the `wordcount` example, I get this:

```
Error initializing attempt_201105161023_0002_m_000011_0:
java.io.IOException: Exception reading file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201105161023_0002/jobToken
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.loadTokens(TokenCache.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1064)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1001)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.startNewTask(TaskTracker.java:2161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$TaskLauncher.run(TaskTracker.java:2125)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201105161023_0002/jobToken does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:400)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:129)
    ... 5 more
```

I created the directory on local file system.

```
$ sudo mkdir /app/hadoop/tmp 
$ sudo chown hadoop:hadoop /app/hadoop/tmp
```

I also modified `core-site.xml`:

```
<!-- In: conf/core-site.xml --> 
<property> 
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name> 
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value> 
  <description>A base for other temporary directories.</description> 
</property>
```

When I format the namenode, it creates the subdirectory on both local 
and HDFS successfully.

When I look at the result of the failed `wordcount` output, the error 
message complains about an I/O error, on file 
`/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/ 
job_201105161023_0002/jobToken`

I did some troubleshooting and can browse to this `jobToken` file on the 
local file system, no problem.  The content is something like `HDTS MapReduce.job 201105161023_0002`

So is it a permission issue?  I made hadoop process user able to write to all the subdirectories and it was able to create the file.  So what else can be wrong?

Some more detailed output from the command line:

```
hadoop@jonathan-VirtualBox:/usr/local/hadoop/hadoop-0.20.203.0$ bin/hadoop jar hadoop-examples-0.20.203.0.jar wordcount app/download app/output4
11/05/16 13:38:56 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 3
11/05/16 13:39:05 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201105161222_0003
11/05/16 13:39:06 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
11/05/16 13:39:17 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000004_0, Status : FAILED
Error initializing attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000004_0:
java.io.IOException: Exception reading file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201105161222_0003/jobToken
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.loadTokens(TokenCache.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1064)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1001)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.startNewTask(TaskTracker.java:2161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$TaskLauncher.run(TaskTracker.java:2125)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201105161222_0003/jobToken does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:400)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:129)
    ... 5 more

11/05/16 13:39:21 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://jonathan-VirtualBox:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000004_0&filter=stdout
11/05/16 13:39:21 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://jonathan-VirtualBox:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000004_0&filter=stderr
11/05/16 13:39:22 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000004_1, Status : FAILED
Error initializing attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000004_1:
java.io.IOException: Exception reading file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201105161222_0003/jobToken
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.loadTokens(TokenCache.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1064)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1001)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.startNewTask(TaskTracker.java:2161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$TaskLauncher.run(TaskTracker.java:2125)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201105161222_0003/jobToken does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:400)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:129)
    ... 5 more

11/05/16 13:39:22 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://jonathan-VirtualBox:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000004_1&filter=stdout
11/05/16 13:39:22 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://jonathan-VirtualBox:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000004_1&filter=stderr
11/05/16 13:39:23 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000004_2, Status : FAILED
Error initializing attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000004_2:
java.io.IOException: Exception reading file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201105161222_0003/jobToken
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.loadTokens(TokenCache.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1064)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1001)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.startNewTask(TaskTracker.java:2161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$TaskLauncher.run(TaskTracker.java:2125)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201105161222_0003/jobToken does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:400)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:129)
    ... 5 more

11/05/16 13:39:23 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://jonathan-VirtualBox:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000004_2&filter=stdout
11/05/16 13:39:23 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://jonathan-VirtualBox:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000004_2&filter=stderr
11/05/16 13:39:30 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000003_0, Status : FAILED
Error initializing attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000003_0:
java.io.IOException: Exception reading file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201105161222_0003/jobToken
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.loadTokens(TokenCache.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1064)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1001)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.startNewTask(TaskTracker.java:2161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$TaskLauncher.run(TaskTracker.java:2125)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201105161222_0003/jobToken does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:400)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:129)
    ... 5 more

11/05/16 13:39:31 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://jonathan-VirtualBox:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000003_0&filter=stdout
11/05/16 13:39:31 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://jonathan-VirtualBox:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000003_0&filter=stderr
11/05/16 13:39:33 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000003_1, Status : FAILED
Error initializing attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000003_1:
java.io.IOException: Exception reading file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201105161222_0003/jobToken
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.loadTokens(TokenCache.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1064)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1001)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.startNewTask(TaskTracker.java:2161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$TaskLauncher.run(TaskTracker.java:2125)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201105161222_0003/jobToken does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:400)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:129)
    ... 5 more

11/05/16 13:39:33 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://jonathan-VirtualBox:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000003_1&filter=stdout
11/05/16 13:39:33 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://jonathan-VirtualBox:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000003_1&filter=stderr
11/05/16 13:39:36 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000003_2, Status : FAILED
Error initializing attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000003_2:
java.io.IOException: Exception reading file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201105161222_0003/jobToken
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.security.TokenCache.loadTokens(TokenCache.java:163)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.initializeJob(TaskTracker.java:1064)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.localizeJob(TaskTracker.java:1001)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker.startNewTask(TaskTracker.java:2161)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TaskTracker$TaskLauncher.run(TaskTracker.java:2125)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/ttprivate/taskTracker/hadoop/jobcache/job_201105161222_0003/jobToken does not exist.
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.getFileStatus(RawLocalFileSystem.java:371)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FilterFileSystem.getFileStatus(FilterFileSystem.java:245)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$ChecksumFSInputChecker.<init>(ChecksumFileSystem.java:125)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.open(ChecksumFileSystem.java:283)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.open(FileSystem.java:400)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.Credentials.readTokenStorageFile(Credentials.java:129)
    ... 5 more

11/05/16 13:39:36 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://jonathan-VirtualBox:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000003_2&filter=stdout
11/05/16 13:39:36 WARN mapred.JobClient: Error reading task outputhttp://jonathan-VirtualBox:50060/tasklog?plaintext=true&attemptid=attempt_201105161222_0003_m_000003_2&filter=stderr
11/05/16 13:39:39 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_201105161222_0003
11/05/16 13:39:39 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 4
11/05/16 13:39:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:   Job Counters 
11/05/16 13:39:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_MAPS=0
11/05/16 13:39:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all reduces waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
11/05/16 13:39:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     Total time spent by all maps waiting after reserving slots (ms)=0
11/05/16 13:39:39 INFO mapred.JobClient:     SLOTS_MILLIS_REDUCES=0
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out your /etc/hosts configuration.
You have to mention master domain name and same for slave.

For eg:
127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain   localhost
107.108.206.64  master ABC-ubuntu
107.108.208.24  slave  XYZ-ubuntu
107.108.87.81   slave1 QWE-ubuntu

Because during reduce processing , it search for XYZ-ubuntu host name instead of slave.

Also, your hosts config should be same in all.

Answer (score 0):

Dont Create /app/hadoop/tmp folder
It will create by default under /tmp/hadoop...

So remove that property from conf file .
It will work