# Shuffle error in mapreduce: Error in shuffle in local fetcher

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hdf

[image: Shuffle_error]

Where should i look for to correct the shuffle error. I have checked yarn-site.xml. I am running a cluster. I tried looking around but couldn't find any helpful stuff.

**yarn-site.xml**

```
<configuration>

<!-- Site specific YARN configuration properties -->

<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services </name>
 <value>mapreduce.shuffle </value>
</property>

<property>
 <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class </name>
 <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>

<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
<value>slave5:8031</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
<value>slave5:8030</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
<value>slave5:8032</value>
</property>



</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the configuration about temp file from core-site.xml. This answer helped me.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11035183/5380111

Remove something like this from core-site.xml:-

```
<property>
  <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name>
  <value>/app/hadoop/tmp</value>
 </property>
```